# How do I get the JSON response from Dialogflow with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, heroku, response, dialogflow-es

I understand the whole process of dialogflow and I have a working deployed bot with 2 different intents. How do I actually get the response from the bot when a user answers questions? (I set the bot on fulfillment to go to my domain). Using rails 5 app and it's deployed with Heroku.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have already set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` path to the jso file, now you can test using a ruby script.

1. Create a ruby file -> ex: `chatbot.rb`
2. Write the code bellow in the file.

> ```
> project_id = "Your Google Cloud project ID"
> session_id = "mysession"
> texts = ["hello"]
> language_code = "en-US"
>
> require "google/cloud/dialogflow"
>
> session_client = Google::Cloud::Dialogflow::Sessions.new
> session = session_client.class.session_path project_id, session_id
> puts "Session path: #{session}"
>
> texts.each do |text|
>   query_input = { text: { text: text, language_code: language_code } }
>   response = session_client.detect_intent session, query_input
>   query_result = response.query_result
>
>   puts "Query text:        #{query_result.query_text}"
>   puts "Intent detected:   #{query_result.intent.display_name}"
>   puts "Intent confidence: #{query_result.intent_detection_confidence}"
>   puts "Fulfillment text:  #{query_result.fulfillment_text}\n"
> end
> ```

3. Insert your project_id. You can find this information on your agent on Dialogflow. Click on the gear on the right side of the Agent's name in the left menu.
4. Run the ruby file in the terminal or in whatever you using to run ruby files. Then you see the bot replying to the "hello" message you have sent.

Obs: Do not forget to install the google-cloud gem:

Answer (score 0):

Not Entirely familiar with Dilogflow, but if you want to receive a response when an action occurs on another app this usually mean you need to receive web-hooks from them

> A WebHook is an HTTP callback: an HTTP POST that occurs when something happens; a simple event-notification via HTTP POST. A web application implementing WebHooks will POST a message to a URL when certain things happen.

I would recommend checking their [fulfillment](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment) documentation for an example. Hope this helps you out.